# windows mount in filesystem

Tags: dual-boot, windows, filesystem

If I mount windows by a GUI means, where is it mounted in the filesystem? From a brief look around, it looks like I can manually mount the windows partition in /mnt or /media, but that doesn't appear to happen automatically if I click on the windows partition to mount it.

Comment: Depends on your OS of choice, and probably also the DE. In Ubuntu, it would be mounted under /media/username/UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last time I tried in Ubuntu (maybe 10.04 or 10.10) ... it mounted in /media/UUID.

this might not help, but in latest linux mint, it is /media/username/UUID.

anyway, you can always run 'mount' command in terminal with normal user and without any arguments, it will tell you where your partition are mounted.

sample output (in this case, my UUID is 0000-AAAA) :

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
................ more partition here .................
/dev/sda6 on /media/rinaldo/0000-AAAA type fat32 (rw)
```